# reactjs: lazy load always not just the first time

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I am using lazy loading in my reactjs project

```
import React, { useState, Suspense } from "react";
const OutgoingTabComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./Outgoing"));
const IncomingTabComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./Incoming"));

<MDBox>
  <MDBox sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
    <Tabs
      value={valueTab}
      onChange={handleChange}
      textColor="secondary"
      indicatorColor="secondary"
    >
      <Tab label="Incoming" {...hare0} />
      <Tab label="Outgoing" {...hare1} />
    </Tabs>
  </MDBox>
  <div
    role="tabpanel"
    hidden={valueTab !== 0}
    id="simple-tabpanel-0"
    aria-labelledby="simple-tab-0"
  >
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
      <IncomingTabComponent />
    </Suspense>
  </div>
  <div
    role="tabpanel"
    hidden={valueTab !== 1}
    id="simple-tabpanel-1"
    aria-labelledby="simple-tab-1"
  >
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
      <OutgoingTabComponent />
    </Suspense>
  </div>
</MDBox>
```

I want this component to always render lazily. I see only when first time loaded it works

I have routes. So when i come back to this page. i want to use lazy loading

Comment: do you mean re-load these components again on the second visit?

Comment: yes. i want the lazy load always

Comment: Because i have big table. whenever i come to this page. i want the table to lazy load always.

Comment: I dont have the direct answer but you have to use lazy in your router or try this lib https://loadable-components.com/ it works good for me

Comment: I even tried to use the lazy in the router also